# Letter g keeps "sticking" on laptop, even though the keyboard is disconnected

Tags: laptop, keyboard, hardware-failure

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 3000 series laptop, and, at first, the letter g stopped working... Taking it off and cleaning it didn't work... No big deal, I just ordered a new keyboard.

Then the g key started sticking sometimes, typing gggggggg anywhere there was a cursor, and trying to select icons starting with g. After a bit longer, it was sticking all the time. It got to where I couldn't even sign in. I can't type my password. It just starts typing endless g's without stopping. (This all happened within about 15 minutes)

Here's the crazy part. I disconnected the keyboard, and started it up. It's STILL TYPING g's! How could it possibly be typing without a keyboard!!!!!??? I tried connecting a USB keyboard and going to safe mode, but it won't recognize F2 or F12 or anything on boot up, because the g's are taking over everything.

All I can do now, is boot to the Win10 login screen, and I can't type my password because it fills up the textbox. That's it. I can't do anything else. I can't even click on the 'ease of access' icon. It won't show it.

Comment: Which keyboard did you disconnect? The one you ordered, plugged through USB, or the one integrated in the laptop, attached to the motherboard?

Comment: I disconnected the integrated keyboard that came with the laptop, (and hadn't connected any other keyboards at that point) so the laptop was getting no keyboard input at all, yet still typing g's.

Comment: Have you tried booting into another OS, or through a live session?

Comment: Yes, it gives me no options to boot another way, other than through a NIC card. I've tried to boot to a USB and CD OS.

Comment: When you first turn on or reboot your notebook, there's a special key or key combination you can press to get into the firmware setup. This varies by manufacturer and model. If the problem isn't the keyboard itself - which it probably isn't, you can go into the setup menus and change the boot order to include USB and/or CDROM before it gets to the internal hard drive. I haven't tried this on a UEFI computer yet, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It sounded like a hardware issue in some ways, but just to be sure, I wiped the hard drive and loaded a different OS (Win10) by changing to Legacy Boot in the BIOS. It solved my problem immediately. So I guess it was software related.